# How can I come up with this design of a header or title in my data table?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: Sample of this is like this]

````
        ```appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),```
````

I used this appBar but got stuck on how to make it look like the sample.

Here is my status about my implementation
[image]

Comment: Add your code snippet

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil i've edited my question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

```
   Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: 10.0,
                height: 50.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Text(
                'DATATABLE',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  letterSpacing: 1,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        DataTable(
          columns: const <DataColumn>[
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                'Name',
                style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                'Birthday',
                style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          rows: const <DataRow>[
            DataRow(
              cells: <DataCell>[
                DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                DataCell(Text('19')),
              ],
            ),
            DataRow(
              cells: <DataCell>[
                DataCell(Text('Janine')),
                DataCell(Text('43')),
              ],
            ),
            DataRow(
              cells: <DataCell>[
                DataCell(Text('William')),
                DataCell(Text('27')),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Your Result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Put `DataTable` in a `Column` just like this:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 200,
              child: Text(
                "Table Title",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 40),
              ),
            ),
            DataTable(
              columns: const <DataColumn>[
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    'Name',
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    'Year',
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    'Lang',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              rows: const <DataRow>[
                DataRow(
                  cells: <DataCell>[
                    DataCell(Text('Duke')),
                    DataCell(Text('1992')),
                    DataCell(Text('Java')),
                  ],
                ),
                DataRow(
                  cells: <DataCell>[
                    DataCell(Text('Dash')),
                    DataCell(Text('2018')),
                    DataCell(Text('Dart')),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```